# Error while installing local repo on AWS for Ambari

Tags: yum, repository, hadoop

I am installing six server node on AWS and while installing hortonworks 2.7.1 on it, i.e. creating local yum repository getting Error:[object Object]

I am able to access through web browser (httpd is working), I can access until

http:///ambari/centos/

but it throws error when trying to go forward

http:///ambari.centod/2.7.1.0-169/ - gives error

Anyhelp much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue while build the local repository for Ambari.

I tried this and worked for me,

There are too many index files available in

```
/var/www/html/ambari/centos7/2.7.3.0-139/
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users 1624 Dec 11  2018 artifacts.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  496 Dec 11  2018 public_index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  497 Dec 11  2018 private_index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  506 Dec 11  2018 index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  501 Dec 11  2018 hotfix_index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users 1667 Dec 11  2018 build_metadata.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  586 Dec 11  2018 build.id
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 users  376 Dec 11  2018 ambari.repo
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 users   32 Dec 11  2018 RPM-GPG-KEY
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 users 4096 Dec 11  2018 ambari
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 users   56 Dec 11  2018 smartsense
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001 users 4096 Dec 11  2018 repodata
drwxr-xr-x. 5 1001 users   65 Dec 11  2018 tars
```

I tried moving all the index pages into separate directory in the same place and cleared the browser cache then tried and it works.

You can try and share your experience.